# Github Actions - How to Parse Tag Annotations

Tags: git, github-actions, git-tag

I am trying to move one Jenkins pipeline to Github Actions. In this pipeline, we deploy from feature branches using a CLI, for example:

```
deploy --env develop --region us-west-2 --pkg service1 service2 service3
```

The Github Actions workflow starts based on the tag:

```
 on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    tags:
      - 'us-west-2-[0-9]+.[0-9]+'
```

In Jenkins, we can view all the tags using `git tag --points-at ${env.GIT_COMMIT}`. I am trying to do the same in my GH action yaml file:

```
- run: echo "TAG_NAMES=$(git tag --points-at ${{ env.GIT_COMMIT }})" >> $GITHUB_ENV
- run: echo $TAG_NAMES
```

I would expect the tags for all services to get returned like in Jenkins, but instead only 1 is returned in the output.

1. Is there some better way to create a list of all tag names in a Github Actions workflow?
2. Is there some Github Action others have used to do this instead?

Comment: Does your GitHub action make a *full* clone, or a shallow, single-name ("single-branch" but using a tag) clone?

Comment: @torek, it is a simple workflow that uses the `actions/checkout@v3`, `actions/setup-node@v3`, and then tries to print the tag annotations. I learned there is a bug with `actions/checkout@v3` where it deletes the annotations: https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/290 . The workaround is to use `git fetch --tags --force`, but now when I run `git tag --points-at ${{ github.sha }}` I see all tag annotations including ones not in that commit.

Comment: So the answer is that your GitHub action makes a shallow clone without tags, but not because you intended to: instead, it's because `actions/checkout@v3` itself is kind of faulty. But that's the answer then.

Comment: @torek The answer I found is to run `git fetch --tags --force` followed by `git tag --points-at ${{ github.sha }} -n300 | tail -n +2 | jq`. This outputs all the information I need in JSON format. I then use jq to parse what I need from the JSON. It is working well!

Comment: You might be able to get the checkout action do do a full clone with tags (in other setups this typically means adding "depth: 0" somewhere), but otherwise this seems fine. You don't really *need* `jq` here to json-ify the last few output lines but if it makes parsing convenient, there's no reason to avoid it either.